# Setting up Github Pages

Tags: github-pages

My question is about how to create git pages when there is no "launch automatic page generator" in my GitHub account. I tried adding index.html file to master branch. how do i add a theme for that page and it does not displays in the page form instead it just shows the code

Answer (score 1):

First step is to create new repository for your github page.
Core feature is a name of github page.
To make your github page works you need to name it like this:
`your_project_name.github.io`
Start file of your github page will be `index.html`.

**Create a new repository**
[image]

**Upoad `index.html` to your repository.**
[image]

**Code of `index.html` file:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>hello github!</title>
</head>
<body>
hello github!
</body>
</html>
```

**Result:**

[image]

https://github.com/fonjeekay/fonjeekay.github.io

https://fonjeekay.github.io/

After operations you need to wait some time to make your `github.io` page added to the `github.io` server.